# Compile/bundle tesseract into one binary

Tags: c++, tesseract

Is it possible to compile tesseract into one binary?

I use the following to compile a program, but how is it possible to compile tesseract shared libraries into one binary so the program is 100% portable and you dont need tesseract to be installed on the current system?

Its not necessary to compile leptonica into the binary

```
g++ -std=c++11 txtocr.cpp -o txtocr -llept -ltesseract
```

Comment: What is the OS running your Tesseract?

Answer (score 6):

For that you need to use a Static Library, on unix systems they usually ends with the .a extension, and a Shared Library ends with .so

If you only have the .so (or .dylib on mac, .dll on windows) library of the tesseract, then you cannot compile it as a single binary.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-static` argument to `g++` to compile a static binary.

Answer (score -2):

Try [pyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/documentation.html), it support Windows, Linux and OSX.  Below sample command is to create an one file bundle executable.

```
pyinstaller -F /path/to/myscript.py
```

It can be installed by `pip install pyinstaller`, or use MacPorts or Homebrew to install in OSX.

Answer (score -3):

This link below

- https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)

will help you more. Whether you are going to compile from scratch or  uselibraries which are already compiled for you for the desired OS.

Comment: How should that help? It's a link to the official repository, which doesn't answer the question